# How to fetch the information from the third party API and display on your website?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I need to fetch data from this "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=MY_API_KEY" API and display on my site using Class based views in django

Comment: Exposing the API key associated with your account isn't advisable. I'd suggest you revoke/rotate it to avoid it being misused.

Comment: Its not the same API i will be fetching data from, I got it from the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve data from a 3rd party API you can use the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) package.

For example, try adding this view to your application.

**views.py**

```
import json
import requests

from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class NewsDataView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'newsdata.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        news_data = requests.get(
            'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=ece95912ea3746e68826c8eb30e2eb66')
        context['newsdata'] = json.dumps(news_data.json(),
                                         sort_keys=True,
                                         indent=4)
        return context
```

**templates/newsdata.html**

```
<html>
<body>
  <pre>
    {{ newsdata }}
  </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can we save this into our database?

Comment: @im_shankarmahato that’s a separate question... one which is covered in the Django guide and docs (and elsewhere online). Suggest reading up, giving it a shot, and asking a new question on SO if you get stuck.